# variable to a sql column name

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have,

```
var car = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Id = @0", carId);
```

The table "Stock" has image data columns ImgF1, ImgF2, ..., ImgF12.
Now I want to retrieve those images as shown below

```
<ul>
@for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++){
    var imageName = "ImgF" + i;
    if(car.@imageName != null){
        <li>
            <img class="small_image" alt="image" src="@Href("~/Cars/XSThumbnail",carId, new{index = i})">
        </li>
    }else{

    }
}
```

The problem is that car.@imageName or car.imageName don't work as imageName is not the column name but just a variable for column names.

---

So please, if you have any ideas i'll be grateful !!

Comment: Thanks for that tip but, I want to retrieve 11 columns using the same variable "imageName" and confirm whether they are not null before processing the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood the `QuerySingle` method returns a [DynamicRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) instance what [you can index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569137%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) with the column name:

```
@for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++){
    var imageName = "ImgF" + i;
    if(car[imageName] != null){
        <li>
            <img class="small_image" alt="image" 
                 src="@Href("~/Cars/XSThumbnail",carId, new{index = i})">
        </li>
    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if(car.@imageName != null){
```

to

```
if(car[imageName] != null){
```

Good luck.

Comment: No problem, glad we could help.  If one of the answers helped you out, please mark it as accepted :)  Good luck.